# Android, making a large background image scrollable

Tags: android, xml

I am making an android app, and I want to set a large image as the background. However, I only want a small part of this image to display at the startup, and I want to be able to scroll to the rest of the image (by swiping)

This is what I have so far

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background"

     >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="searchmethod"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/filterbutton"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/searchbutton"
        android:onClick="choosefilter"
        android:src="@drawable/filter" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Zoomoutbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/filterbutton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/zoomout"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Zoominbutton"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Zoomoutbutton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Zoomoutbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/zoomin"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This however just displays the entire image in the background, whereas I want a small part of it to display and then scroll across it. I apologize if this was asked already, but I couldn't find any answer that helped me.

EDIT: Ok, I can scroll the image now, but I want my buttons to stay in the corners of my screen at all times. Can anyone help? Currently when I scroll, I am scrolling away from my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the RelativeLayout in a ScrollView. You don't specify vertical or horizontal, so you may need HorizontalScrollView (or both?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ScrollView object which will hold the image. The ScrollView dimensions can be set by you and the rest of the image will then become scrollable.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot to both of you guts. But I have two questions. 1. I need to have both a horizontal and vertical scroll , so do I embed both views in each other?If so, how do the dimensions work? 2. How do I fix my icons on a certain part of the screen at all times?